# Нижняя граница поля ввода под лупой

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, input, flexbox

Есть следующие элементы интерфейса - поле ввода и лупа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно из скриншота нижняя граница поля ввода расположена под лупой. При этом при вводе текста в поле ввода текст не налезает на лупу, а отделен крестиком

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно достичь этого, чтобы текст не налезал на лупу. а нижняя граница поля ввода была расположена под лупой? (желательно без float, но можно с флексом)

Привожу код для родителя

```css
.crossline, .bottompart {
    flex: 1;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*height: 33%;*/
}

.crosslineright {
    width: 100%;
    /*margin-top: 40px;*/
    /*margin-left: 20px;*/
    /*margin-right: 20px;*/
    /*align: right;*/
    text-align: right;
}

.close {
        margin-top: -14px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        font-size: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
}

.CatalogMenuSearch {
    border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}

#SearchBlock {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  display: flex;
  height: 35px;
  border-bottom: 1px;
}

#SearchInputdiv {
  height: 100%;
}

#SearchButtondiv {
  height: 100%;
}

#SearchButton button svg {
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdownwindowright">
  <div class="crosslineright">
    <div class="close">&times;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="CatalogMenuSearch">
    <div id="SearchBlock">
      <div id="SearchInputdiv">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск по товарам" id="SearchInput">
      </div>
      <div id="SearchButtondiv">
        <button id="SearchButton"><svg class=" Icon" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M5.22703 5.22703C7.86307 2.591 12.1369 2.591 14.773 5.22703C17.2298 7.68382 17.3968 11.5632 15.2742 14.2135L19.0607 18L18 19.0607L14.2135 15.2742C11.5632 17.3968 7.68381 17.2298 5.22703 14.773C2.59099 12.1369 2.59099 7.86307 5.22703 5.22703ZM13.7123 6.28769C11.6621 4.23744 8.33794 4.23744 6.28769 6.28769C4.23744 8.33795 4.23744 11.6621 6.28769 13.7123C8.33794 15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 13.7123 13.7123C15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 8.33795 13.7123 6.28769Z"></path></svg></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="CatalogMenuRight">
  </div>
</div>
```

В результате на экран выводится

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В блоке с классом `.CatalogMenuSearch` задана нижняя рамка - `border-bottom: 1px`, которая не отображается.

Comment: Например, родительскому элементу указать `position: relative;`, а кнопке с лупой `position: absolute;` и указать как отступы, так и габариты. Вообще же, здесь принято задавать вопросы, размещая в них не только скриншоты.

Comment: 1. Родителю назначить `display: flex` и "нарисовать" нижнюю рамку. 2. Деткам: инпуту и кнопке задать расположение, а кнопке ещё и размеры.

Comment: Читайте про css свойства. Вам поможет border-bottom.

Comment: @Quazimorda я привел код - нижняя рамка не отображается.

Comment: Ещё раз: читайте про то как устанавливаются свойства css. Вы указали только толщину линии, а необходимо было ещё указать её тип и цвет. Как-то так: `border-bottom: 1px solid orange;`

Comment: И ещё совет: не нужно создавать селекторы в стиле CamelCase, используйте kebab-case. Почитайте и об этом. В частности, `#SearchBlock` стоило бы заменить на `#search-block`. Ну и прочие стили тоже.

Comment: Присоединюсь к комментарию выше про CamelCase, так же добавлю что использовать ID в вёрстке для CSS это отвратительный тон, дайте элементам классы. С ними и работайте. Вообще в целом Вам бы CSS азы изучить для начала.

Comment: @Quazimorda см. комментарий после ответа Alexandr.

Answer (score 1):

В первую очередь хочу заметить, что в режиме разработчика на сайте все стили видны, не понимаю в чём проблема их скопировать. Ну окей.
Решение:

```css
.crossline, .bottompart {
    flex: 1;
    /*width: 100%;*/
    /*height: 33%;*/
}

.crosslineright {
    width: 100%;
    /*margin-top: 40px;*/
    /*margin-left: 20px;*/
    /*margin-right: 20px;*/
    /*align: right;*/
    text-align: right;
}

input[type=text]::-ms-clear {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
input[type=text]::-ms-reveal {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration { display: none; }

.close {
        margin-top: -14px;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
        font-size: 24px;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: inline-block;
}

#SearchBlock {
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-right: 50px;
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px;
}

#SearchInputdiv {
  position: relative;
}

#SearchInput, #SearchInput:focus {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
  outline: none;
}

#SearchButtondiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 0;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#SearchButton {
  background-color: transparent;
  outline:none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#SearchButton svg {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  fill: #b3b3b7;
}

#SearchButton svg:hover {
  fill: orange;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropdownwindowright">
  <div class="crosslineright">
    <div class="close">&times;</div>
  </div>
  <div class="CatalogMenuSearch">
    <div id="SearchBlock">
      <div id="SearchInputdiv">
        <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск по товарам" id="SearchInput">
        <div id="SearchButtondiv">
        <button id="SearchButton">
          <svg class=" Icon" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M5.22703 5.22703C7.86307 2.591 12.1369 2.591 14.773 5.22703C17.2298 7.68382 17.3968 11.5632 15.2742 14.2135L19.0607 18L18 19.0607L14.2135 15.2742C11.5632 17.3968 7.68381 17.2298 5.22703 14.773C2.59099 12.1369 2.59099 7.86307 5.22703 5.22703ZM13.7123 6.28769C11.6621 4.23744 8.33794 4.23744 6.28769 6.28769C4.23744 8.33795 4.23744 11.6621 6.28769 13.7123C8.33794 15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 13.7123 13.7123C15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 8.33795 13.7123 6.28769Z"></path></svg>
        </button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="CatalogMenuRight">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: текст, вводимый в поле ввода, налезает на кнопку с лупой.

Answer (score 1):

Как по мне, то уж больно много лишнего в коде нагорожено. Убрал кое-что лишнее: в вёрстке оставил только средний блок, в стилях тоже оставил только то, что имеет отношение к делу. Получилось примерно так:

```css
#SearchBlock {
  display: flex;
  border-bottom: 1px solid orange;
}

.close {
  font-size: 24px;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}

#SearchInput {
  border: 0;
  outline: none;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

input[type=text]::-ms-clear {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
input[type=text]::-ms-reveal {  display: none; width : 0; height: 0; }
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-button,
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-results-decoration { display: none; }

#SearchButton {
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline:none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#SearchButton svg {
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  fill: #b3b3b7;
}
```

```html
<div id="SearchBlock">
  <input type="search" placeholder="Поиск по товарам" id="SearchInput">
  <div class="close">&times;</div>
  <div id="SearchButtondiv">
    <button id="SearchButton">
      <svg class=" Icon" width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M5.22703 5.22703C7.86307 2.591 12.1369 2.591 14.773 5.22703C17.2298 7.68382 17.3968 11.5632 15.2742 14.2135L19.0607 18L18 19.0607L14.2135 15.2742C11.5632 17.3968 7.68381 17.2298 5.22703 14.773C2.59099 12.1369 2.59099 7.86307 5.22703 5.22703ZM13.7123 6.28769C11.6621 4.23744 8.33794 4.23744 6.28769 6.28769C4.23744 8.33795 4.23744 11.6621 6.28769 13.7123C8.33794 15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 13.7123 13.7123C15.7626 11.6621 15.7626 8.33795 13.7123 6.28769Z"></path>
      </svg>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```